# Why doesn't Firefox honour non-clashing custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, display, firefox

(Similar to [How can I set Firefox to respect my custom Mac keyboard shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/373082/142445), but that's about custom keyboard shortcuts that clash with Firefox's own shortcuts. This question is not.)

I have added two custom shortcuts for moving windows between monitors:

- ⌥⇧⌘↑ to move up, and
- ⌥⇧⌘↓ to move down

[image: app keyboard shortcuts screenshot]

These (as far as I know) do not clash with any Firefox keyboard shortcuts, but unlike my other applications Firefox ignores them. Why? How might I fix this?

(N.B. I am using multiple Firefox profiles, via `about:profiles`.)

Comment: It's not strictly true that all my other apps work, VSCode sometimes does and sometimes doesn't :(

Comment: Does Firefox have those precise menu options? [Can't test here because I have neither of those options, anywhere]

Comment: @Tetsujin, no Firefox does not have those precise menu options, hence why I mention that the shortcuts are _non-clashing_, i.e. they do not clash with any of Firefox's built in shortcuts

Comment: If it doesn't have the menu option, there's nothing to action. It cannot work unless it does have the option. Any shortcut in the Apps shortcut section is a rather clever 'direct menu item call'… but  it's not a 'function' in itself.